# How to sort array data using another array as a template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort a dynamically generated JavaScript array against a 'master' array. This master array is to be used as the template for how to sort the dynamically generated array. The master array, however, may have new items added in the future, but such items would be added manually.

**The array that needs to be sorted is:**

```
var arrayToSort = ['ABCD','ABCD 123 Team','IMT_User_MNOP'];
```

**The master array is:**

```
var roleDef = ['IMT_User_MNOP','IMT_User_User','ABCD','ABCD 123 Team','ABCD Plans'];
```

I've browsed nearly all solutions here at SO, and none of them deal with sorting an array against another array based on having a non-matching number of items and sorting the index value `===` index value. And other solutions deal with keys, or sorting numbers based on letters (or letters based on numbers), etc.

I appreciate any help someone can provide, even if it is just to point me in the right direction so I can figure this out.

Comment: Are the elements of the to-be-sorted array always a subset of the master array? Then you practically filter the master array against the search array. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arrayToSort = ['ABCD','ABCD 123 Team','IMT_User_MNOP'];
var roleDef = ['IMT_User_MNOP','IMT_User_User','ABCD','ABCD 123 Team','ABCD Plans'];


var newArr = arrayToSort.map(function(item){
  var idx = roleDef.indexOf(item);
  
  return {
    val:item,
    roleDefIndex:idx
  };
});
var result = newArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.roleDefIndex - b.roleDefIndex;
}).map(function(item){
  return item.val;
});
console.log(result);
```

Other version

```js
var arrayToSort = ['ABCD','ABCD 123 Team','IMT_User_MNOP'];
var roleDef = ['IMT_User_MNOP','IMT_User_User','ABCD','ABCD 123 Team','ABCD Plans'];

var IndexWithinRole = {};
 arrayToSort.forEach(function(item){
  IndexWithinRole[item] = roleDef.indexOf(item);
});
arrayToSort.sort(function(a, b) {
  return IndexWithinRole[a] - IndexWithinRole[b];
});
console.log(arrayToSort);
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solutions doesn't sort in my application. What I get is: `Final View List (Sorted): ABCD,ABCD 123 Team,IMT_User_MNOP`. I've tried both of your solutions.

Comment: I still get the same sorting as I mentioned in my previous comment. Your code output is correct, but I don't get the same when I put your code into mine.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or a code snippet with your code , because in my snippet everything it's ok

Comment: Sure. Give me a few minutes and I'll post the entire function into a JSFiddle.

Comment: your roleDefViews was array of arrays      userViewListUnique.forEach(function (item) {
                IndexWithinRole[item] = roleDefViews[0].indexOf(item);
            });

Comment: you can get the fix from the fiddle

Comment: Thank you for your help Vladu.

Comment: or instead of push in array just get it's value     roleDefViews = omitData.viewroleconditions.roleviewdefinitions.views; and use roleDefViews.indexOf(item) instead of roleDefViews[0].indexOf(item);

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a hash table for the wanted sort order with a default value wheather the not defined values should go to start or to the end.

> ```
> {
>     "IMT_User_MNOP": 1,
>     "IMT_User_User": 2,
>     "ABCD": 3,
>     "ABCD 123 Team": 4,
>     "ABCD Plans": 5
> }
> ```

```js
var arrayToSort = ['ABCD', 'ABCD 123 Team', 'IMT_User_MNOP'],
    roleDef = ['IMT_User_MNOP', 'IMT_User_User', 'ABCD', 'ABCD 123 Team', 'ABCD Plans'],
    roleObj = Object.create(null);

roleDef.forEach(function (a, i) { roleObj[a] = i + 1; });

arrayToSort.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (roleObj[a] || 0) - (roleObj[b] || 0);
});

console.log(arrayToSort);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I could use a hash table. The array 'roleDef' is already in a json file, and maintained by others. And I'm not sure if they are willing to change the format at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I simply did this but haven't got the time to check if it's silly or not

```js
var arrayToSort = ['ABCD','ABCD 123 Team','IMT_User_MNOP'],
        roleDef = ['IMT_User_MNOP','IMT_User_User','ABCD','ABCD 123 Team','ABCD Plans'];
arrayToSort.sort((a,b) => roleDef.indexOf(a) - roleDef.indexOf(b));
console.log(arrayToSort);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going with `Array.indexOf()` which produces a **O(n²)** solution, use:

```js
var roleDef = ['IMT_User_MNOP','IMT_User_User','ABCD','ABCD 123 Team','ABCD Plans'];
var arrayToSort = ['ABCD','ABCD 123 Team','IMT_User_MNOP'];

var sorted = roleDef.filter(role => arrayToSort.indexOf(role) >= 0);

console.log(sorted);
```

If you need more performance for bigger arrays, go with @NinaScholz's answer and precompute a hashmap from your `roleDef`.